# How to construct an object from a tuple when it does not have any constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, tuples

If I have a class which has a defined constructor:

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point(int x, int y);
    // ...
};
```

And a `std::tuple`:

```
using Tuple = std::tuple<int,int>;
```

I can construct the class using the tuple by calling `std::make_from_tuple`:

```
void f()
{
    Tuple tuple = {1,2};
    auto point = std::make_from_tuple<Point>(tuple);
}
```

If e.g. my class is using only factory methods and has no defined constructor:

```
class Point
{
    Point() = delete;

public:
    static Point from_coordinates(int x, int y);
    // ...
};
```

Apparently I cannot customize `std::make_from_tuple` to use anything else to act as a constructor.

Is there a more generic implementation of `std::make_from_tuple` available in STL or in Boost? Is it possible to use anything else to achieve the same result?

Comment: If you look up make_from_tuple on cppreference.com, you will see exactly what it does, and you should be able to simply adapt it to use your factory method. Which is pretty close to what `std::apply` does. You can probably feed a lambda to `std::apply` that forwards its arguments to your factory.

Comment: Is there a reason not to implement `Point(Tuple xy);` constructor?

Comment: @Eljay assume class code is from third party and you cannot change it

Comment: Then you could make a freestanding `Point to_Point(Tuple xy);` factory function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) to call `from_coordinates` with a `std::tuple`.  That would look like

```
auto point = std::apply(Point::from_coordinates, tuple);
```